# Firebase authentication with another API

Tags: mongodb, angular, express, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am wondering if it is possible to use just the Firebase authentication system together with your own API and database.

It has some nice features I want to take advantage of, however I do not wish to use their database or storage.

The application I am building is an Angular2 and express application with a MongoDB database.

Any answers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That definitely is possible: you can create your own identity provider that plugs into Firebase Authentication. This is often referred to as custom authentication. To implement this, you need a server (or other trusted process) where you authenticate your users and [mint security tokens for then](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). You then pass this token to the user and have them [pass it into Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

But keep in mind: many Firebase features work fine without authentication. For example: if you use Cloud Messaging, Crash Reporting, Test Lab or many other features, you might not need to implement Firebase Authentication at all.

Comment: I will have a look into this. I am guessing that the custom auth will accept JWT tokens coming from my server? Really I am just wanting to use Firebase auth because it is relatively easy to use, and everything is more or less.done for you